# how to handle error from emails not found when sending emails?

Tags: sql, asp.net, email

in my project i'm creating a mailing system which sends 5000 emails at once, if just one email not written correctly( email may be writen like la@lala.net instead of bla@lala.net) in the database the project shuts down and no emails sent
i want to handle this error so it tells me which email is not right, but still complete to send to all the right ones
i'm not talking about email validation here (already done) i'm talking about the email not found at the receiving server
and thanks in advance :)

```
List<string> bla = (from c in DB.tbl select c.email).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < bla.Count(); i++)
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(TBsendermail.Text);
            msg.To.Add(bla[i]);
            msg.Subject = TBemailsubject.Text;
            msg.Body = "";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "mail.blabla.net";
            System.Net.NetworkCredential networkcrd = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail", "pass");
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = networkcrd;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Send(msg);
```

the error come like this
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was:  No such user here

Comment: You should include a code snippet in your question. It's very hard to say, how do you handle errors.

Comment: What is your emailing services ?  There are numerous indications for an EMail including whether it has been received on the target or not.    Waht do you mean by "not written correctly" ?  And error with the email structure ? with the headers ?  Are you preparing a queue and then sending the emails ?

Comment: i added part of the code for sending and will add the error that comes up
and email not written correctly means email may be written like la@lala.net instead of bla@lala.net

Comment: There are pretty good methods on SO for mail validation, best would be before sending, to run that mail validation, and add to the list only valid ones and then start mail sending, after sending is done, report back non-valid mails to users ... just google it

Comment: all email's formats are correct, i've done this, the point is that email may never exist because of misspelling (andro@gmail instead of andrew@gmail)